# What is the best practice to lazy-load model-objects in JSF

Tags: jsf, lazy-loading

I am developing a web-application, and want to use lazy loading in the models. 
Therefore I have adapted the getter-methods and check if the value is null (and not loaded) and if so, it requests this value from the db.

the problem is now, that if many values are not loaded at a point and I access them (the getter) e.g. from the xhtml-page, it creates lots of db-connections with each little queries inside.

I am now wondering, how such a lazy-loaded model is implemented in big web-applications (e.g. e-commerce). Do they have a "pool" where all once data is cached so first the cache is checked and only then the db accessed? or is it better to use a applications-scoped DB-Connection which is permanently open so creating new connections is avoided?

How should I implement my loading-strategy for models, which are loaded as needed on page access but lazy loads all additional elements?

for example we have following chapter-structure in DB:

1. chapter
   1.1 chapter
   1.2 chapter
   1.2.1 chapter

The page "x" loads chapter 1.1, but without parent and children (only the name and its id). when the user opens it, it should load also the children (lazy) and so on...

Comment: You are already using PrimeFaces in which lazy loading is already supported which is associated with several iterating components. To the connection/connection pooling, everything is supported out of the box by average application servers (thus, there is no need to reinvent the wheel) such as connection pooling, transaction management (container managed transactions and if you need, bean managed transactions are also available, for example, if you need to access a database outside the service layer for some certain special cases (web layer, for example)), security and many more.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I am using Tomcat 7. if I create a new connection element (JDBC), is it really pooled somewhere? Doesn't is create new connections every time due to I cannot check if there is a pooled connection somewhere? Does Tomcat support this out of the box and how can I check if it works?